# Range for snapshot listener in Firestore with Swift

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

Is it possible to get Documents with a value between a range instead of isEqual e.g.

```
db.collection("Person").whereField("age", isEqualTo: 15...21).addSnapshotListener {
```

This is what I tried. The build succeed but I got this error:

"Unsupported type: __SwiftValue"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify multiple where clauses to specify the range.
e.g.

```
db.collection("Person").whereField("age", isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 15).whereField("age", isLessThan: 21). addSnapshotListener{
```

For more details on compound queries, you can refer to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#swift)